# Autofill by next column over with indirect formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ms-office

I was wondering why the formula I did won't go to the next column over. I did place the $ sign to stay in the same row, but not on the column, thinking it will go to the next column over. Is there any suggestions as to why this is doing this?

The following is the formula I inputted into the spreadsheet:

`=(INDIRECT("BHR8732A2!P$16"))*$S283`

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to get here? The formula reproduced here would work the same without the Indirect element as `='BHR8732A2'!$P$16*$S283` - that is, it would get the value in cell P16 of sheet BHR8732A2 and multiply it by the value in S283. The indirect in this case is extraneous.

Comment: `INDIRECT()` tries to create cell reference from string and combing two strings requires either `&` between them or `CONCATENATE()`. For this case `INDIRECT()` is redundant and you should just go with formula from @Werrf

Comment: Sometimes several columns will be deleted, and I need the values to be references to the same cell regardless if the column gets deleted or not.

Comment: Do you mean that the formula needs to reference the same cell *address*, regardless of which cells are inserted or deleted, or it needs to reference the same *cell*, regardless of how the address of that cell may change?

Comment: needs to reference the same cell address

Comment: Hmm. Difficult. We want it to be relative as it's going in, but then become absolute after it's been inserted. We may be looking at using a macro to insert the formulae...

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `" "` around the sheet and cell reference `BHR8732A2!P$16`, it's going to be treated as a text string, not a cell reference. It's not going to change when you copy across.

If you want to just multiply the value in column S by the value in row 16, you'd write it as `='BHR8732A2'!P$16*$S283`.

If you want to multiply the value in column S by the value in another cell whose address is in row 16, you'd write it as `=INDIRECT('BHR8732A2'!P$16)*$S283`.

Using a text string inside the Indirect is kind of the 'worst of both worlds', where you're just feeding the cell reference directly into the Indirect, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why the whole `BHR8732A2!P$16` has quotes. Excel does not seem to recognise the `P$16` part as a cell reference for me.

Try this: `=(INDIRECT('BHR8732A2'!P$16))*$S283`

Comment: aww I tried but it didnt' work. Thanks for the help tho!